ElasticBeanstalk Docker app is allowing CORS all origins
We have a Docker application which we are deploying to AWS via the EB CLI and a Docker compose file. There is a load balancer that sits in front of the EC2 instance to setup SSL and forwarding rules to the different containers.
Everything is running but when I scan with ZAP it says there is a critical alert with the CORS headers. The ZAP tool tries a request with a randomly generated Origin and the application is responding with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin for that made up Origin. Basically the app is allowing all Origins and this is a potential vulnerability.
I have tested this running the containers locally and the ZAP tool doesn't find this problem. This makes me suspicious of either the LB or perhaps how Docker is running on the EC2. I've tried searching online and through the docs but can't find anything that helps. I have also searched through the console to see what settings I can twiddle but haven't found anything CORS related.
How can I change the CORS settings to not allow all origins?

I thought this was a setting in AWS because the scan only picked up the CORS alert there and not when run locally. I spent a lot of time looking through docs etc and came to the conclusion that this allowing all origins could not be setup on the AWS side in the LB.
Instead it had to be coming from the application. It turned out there were a few different versions of the application config floating about and the one used in the cloud had this CORS rule. I have tidied this up now so everyone is using the same config without the allow all origins rule and the ZAP scan now passes.
